# Resize table column with fixed header in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have table with horizontal and vertical scroll where header is fixed. As I'm using fixed header the clone is generated for header so the resizing is not working on it. I need to resize the table columns also. Please help me...

Here is the code : http://jsfiddle.net/manishan/Hx7ak/

Comment: Can you post some code? What have you tried?

Comment: thanks for reply. I have added link for the code.

Comment: There are quite good plugins for this. If you want to use a plugin i recommend flexigrid. Check this page for flexigrid and other alternatives http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-grids/

Answer (score 5):

I didn't see anyone mentioning the DataTables.net plugin as it has some addons that work for these cases. It's totally customizable, and extendable.

For some reason my jsfiddle was showing me errors that I could not debug, but when tried in here with xammp it worked perfectly and rendered pagination, column sorting and fixed header examples.. as you can see the initialization code is quite short, but you might want to download de codebase for the imagery. I basically took your provided code elements and arrange it to apply DataTables.net jQuery plugin.

## HTML

```
                <!DOCTYPE html> 
                                <html lang="en">
                                <head>
                                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                                    <title>
                                TEST DataTables.net plugin - Fixed Header example
                                </title>
                                <script src='jquery182.js' ></script>
                                <script src='jquery.dataTables.js' ></script>
                                <script src='FixedHeader.js' ></script>
                                <link rel='stylesheet' href='demo_table.css'/>
                                <link rel='stylesheet' href='demo_page.css'/>
                                </head>
                                <body>
                                <div id="demo">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display data_Table" >
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>

                                     <th style='width:47px; height:29px' >
                                 <input  name="chkSelectAll" type="checkbox" value="" id="chkSelectAll"/></th>
                                            <th style='width:159px;font-weight:bold'>Computer <span class="actdiv">&nbsp;</span></th>
                                            <th style='width:105px;font-weight:bold'>Group <span class="actdiv">&nbsp;</span></th>
                                            <th style='width:97px;font-weight:bold'>Policy <span class="actdiv">&nbsp;</span></th>
                                            <th style='width:105px;font-weight:bold'>Domain <span class="actdiv">&nbsp;</span></th>
                                            <th style='width:126px;font-weight:bold'>Address<span class="actdiv">&nbsp;</span></th>
                                            <th style='width:127px;font-weight:bold'>Type <span class="actdiv">&nbsp;</span></th>
                                            <th style='width:109px;font-weight:bold'>Status <span class="actdiv">&nbsp;</span></th>
                                            <th style='width:181px;font-weight:bold'>Test Status  <span class="actdiv">&nbsp;</span></th>
                                            <th style='width:165px;font-weight:bold'>Version <span class="actdiv">&nbsp;</span></th>
                                            <th style='width:131px;font-weight:bold'>Date <span class="actdiv">&nbsp;</span></th>
                                            <th style='width:160px;font-weight:bold'>Last Date <span class="actdiv">&nbsp;</span></th>
                                            <th style='width:173px;font-weight:bold'>Count </th>

                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>


                                    <tbody>

  <tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr><tr style="padding-left:10px">
                                            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" alt="classid-1" class="chkSelectAll" style="z-index:-2"/></td>
                                            <td class="name">DEVBUILD1</td>
                                            <td class="groupId">test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                            <td>test</td>
                                          </tr> </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </div>

    <script>
                                jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                                    var oTable = $('.data_Table').dataTable( {
                                        // "sDom": 'RC<"clear">lfrtip'
                                    //options: we are using
                                            "sDom": 'Rlfrtip',
                                            "sScrollY": "200px",
                                            "bPaginate": true         //Disable pagination false


                                    } );
                                });
                                </script>
                                </body>
                </html>
```

## INCLUDE JS & CSS from JSFIDDLE LINK

- **JSFiddle  Link:** [http://jsfiddle.net/Hx7ak/60/][1]

If you take the source code at the HTML section for that jsfiddle, and download the dependencies from that jsfiddle link (the javascript and css files, and place this html within the same directory) it should get you started in no time with it.

Although, depending on which options you might want to look into shall you decide to go for this jQuery plugin, keep in mind that it has a very active community and support and at the forums the developers should be masters with specifics.

## For more check on DataTables.net the example section.

Interesting links that can help you depending on how you would like to present your data with this plugin are:

## FixedHeader

- http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedHeader/two_tables.html
- http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedHeader/index.html
- http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedHeader/html_table.html

## ColReorder

- http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/ColReorder/scrolling.html
- http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/ColReorder/fixedheader.html
- http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/ColReorder/fixedcolumns.html

## Colvis (Seems interesting)

- http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/ColVis/index.html

## FixedColumns

- http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/index.html

Well as you can see at http://www.datatables.net/examples/ the list of examples is quite long, but hope this helps!

[image: DataTables implementation 1]
[image: DataTables implementation 2]

## Expected results with this jQuery Plugin

Comment: Hi Prahalad, sorry that I don't quite understand your statement. There are many options within the specific plugin that I have mentioned... In fact, I have used it myself on the process of updating some proprietary of my client software and it has proven to work for any case that the end client have tried to think of.. I mean with this that is well backed up by it's own community and last time that I have checked Alan (the DataTables.net plugin author) is very responsive to any questions that you might have.. Having said that, please check it out at http://datatables.net

Comment: I wanted to re-size the table column just like we do in Excel with the help of mouse!!

Comment: Prahalad, I will need to look further into this for the DataTables plugin, although I'm not sure if what you are looking for is the default functionality it could exist somewhere.. please take into consideration that Excel is a program while DataTables might have an option to redraw the columns, is something that might need to need some sort of listener on each interaction.. I'm not definitely sure as I have not tried, but will do and let you know.. :)

Comment: @Luv I don't really think that the functionality that you are querying about exists just yet, although I might be wrong. From the DataTables website, there is a custom search.. I did see many interesting plugins and addons for this, although I never needed to edit the product of the table as columns to be editable, I believe that it worth typing those comments in a response

Answer (score 4):

**Useful jQuery Plugins for Working with Tabular or table-based content 
** (*include re-sizable columns and fixed header*)

- [Flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info/)
- [Ingrid](http://reconstrukt.com/ingrid/src/example1.html)
- [jQuery Grid](http://makoomba.altervista.org/grid/)
- [jQuery DataTables table-plugin](http://datatables.net) (See Jean Paul's answer ;) )

OCT 28 2015: Edited due one link being unavailable for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** For resizable columns and fixed header try this plugin http://www.tablefixedheader.com/fullpagedemo/ which lets you resize the header along with  the columns.

---

I recently wrote a plugin for fixed header column tables. Which is basically to address the issue with the scrollable table in which the header and columns goes out of view while scrolling.

Check out the the plugin demo page @Git: http://meetselva.github.com/fixed-table-rows-cols/

And the full page demo of your HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/ryB2n/4/embedded/result/

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ryB2n/4/

Also this plugin supports fixed columns which can configured using `fixedCols` option. Note that it is just an optional configuration, so without that option would render you the fixed header table.

**Note:** I am still working on that plugin to handle exception cases and other features, so please use it with caution.

Comment: thanks for the information but if you see the question very carefully then the main part is "I need to resize the table columns also.".. i guess resize is not suported in your plugin.. or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a peek on this website: http://bz.var.ru/comp/web/resizable.html
There is a resizable columns script there, which you could extract and implement in your code.

Answer (score 0):

@Luv /    Not sure if I understood fully your reference to excel.exe vs the resize with a mouse drag scenario described in your question, but I will try to respond with what I have been able to work with so far in regards to DataTables plus some reading and considerations while browsing their website (http://www.datatables.net)

There is a very cool plugin (haven't tried it myself) that allows you to do CRUD (Create-Read-Update-Delete cycle of programming.. In case that you are working with some local storage or a DB based approach for holding your applications Data) Furthermore, I can't really guess which is the functionality that you are finally aiming to, here are some thoughts to consider:

Paid Plugin for DataTables (Editor plugin)

http://editor.datatables.net/release/DataTables/extras/Editor/examples/events_keySubmit.html

Costs like $15 bucks for the license, if I am not mistaken, but comes built-in with a bunch of ready for CRUD developing api, which seems really cool.. I think that it uses some sort of facebox modal window opening on triggered events. Worth a try!

If you are wanting to edit the DataTables inline, I think that there is a plugin for that

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/editable.html

(dataTables created by Allan Jardine appears to be very supported by it's community and I would suggest that if you are planning on developing with it, you ought to become a regular at their forums, or posts questions to Allan as far as if that desired functionality you are looking for has been developed for this current stable version of his interesting work).

On the other hand, if what you are looking for is to edit the columns width as a jQuery UI resizable method, I believe that you need to hook the function redraw, and write a custom extension of something like this example:

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html

Also, you might be interested in looking at: (http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) to learn more about how you can prototype reworking the columns on fnReDraw (which is very useful for hooking events when we use the sort by or filtering options from DaTatables) with some chained events programming.

I have not tried this, but it could work as a last resort... Happy coding ;)

Answer (score -1):

Just Use below line of code That will work.

```
$(window).on('resize', function () { $('.fixedHeader').remove(); new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table); });
```